# Kubernetes: weave picked the public IP on one of the worker nodes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, weave

I have a 2 master and 2 worker kubernetes cluster. Each node has private IP in the range 192.168.5.X and public IP.
After creating the weave daemonset, the weave pod picked the correct internal IP on one node but on the other node it picked the public IP. Is there any way we can instruct weave pod to pick the private IP on the node?

Im creating the cluster from scratch by doing everything manually on the VMs created on Virtual Box on local laptop. I refer the below link

https://github.com/mmumshad/kubernetes-the-hard-way

After deploying weave pods on worker node, weave pod on one of the worker nodes uses the NAT ip as below.

10.0.2.15 is the NAT IP and 192.168.5.12 is internal IP

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide
NAME              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE      NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
weave-net-p4czj   2/2     Running   2          26h   192.168.5.12   worker1   <none>           <none>
weave-net-pbb86   2/2     Running   8          25h   10.0.2.15      worker2   <none>           <none>
```

```
[@master1 ~]$ kubectl describe node
Name:               worker1
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=worker1
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 10 Dec 2019 02:07:09 -0500
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Conditions:
  Type                 Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----                 ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 04:50:15 -0500   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 04:50:15 -0500   WeaveIsUp                    Weave pod has set this
  MemoryPressure       False   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 07:13:43 -0500   Tue, 10 Dec 2019 02:09:09 -0500   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure         False   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 07:13:43 -0500   Tue, 10 Dec 2019 02:09:09 -0500   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure          False   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 07:13:43 -0500   Tue, 10 Dec 2019 02:09:09 -0500   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready                True    Wed, 11 Dec 2019 07:13:43 -0500   Tue, 10 Dec 2019 04:16:26 -0500   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  192.168.5.12
  Hostname:    worker1
Capacity:
 cpu:                1
 ephemeral-storage:  14078Mi
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             499552Ki
 pods:               110
Allocatable:
 cpu:                1
 ephemeral-storage:  13285667614
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             397152Ki
 pods:               110
System Info:
 Machine ID:                 455146bc2c2f478a859bf39ac2641d79
 System UUID:                D4C6F432-3C7F-4D27-A21B-D78A0D732FB6
 Boot ID:                    25160713-e53e-4a9f-b1f5-eec018996161
 Kernel Version:             4.4.206-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
 OS Image:                   CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
 Operating System:           linux
 Architecture:               amd64
 Container Runtime Version:  docker://18.6.3
 Kubelet Version:            v1.13.0
 Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.13.0
Non-terminated Pods:         (2 in total)
  Namespace                  Name                   CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                  ----                   ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                    ng1-6677cd8f9-hws8n    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         26h
  kube-system                weave-net-p4czj        20m (2%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         26h
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests  Limits
  --------           --------  ------
  cpu                20m (2%)  0 (0%)
  memory             0 (0%)    0 (0%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)    0 (0%)
Events:              <none>


Name:               worker2
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=worker2
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 10 Dec 2019 03:14:01 -0500
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Conditions:
  Type                 Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----                 ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 04:50:32 -0500   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 04:50:32 -0500   WeaveIsUp                    Weave pod has set this
  MemoryPressure       False   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 07:13:43 -0500   Tue, 10 Dec 2019 03:14:03 -0500   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure         False   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 07:13:43 -0500   Tue, 10 Dec 2019 03:14:03 -0500   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure          False   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 07:13:43 -0500   Tue, 10 Dec 2019 03:14:03 -0500   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready                True    Wed, 11 Dec 2019 07:13:43 -0500   Tue, 10 Dec 2019 03:56:47 -0500   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  10.0.2.15
  Hostname:    worker2
Capacity:
 cpu:                1
 ephemeral-storage:  14078Mi
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             499552Ki
 pods:               110
Allocatable:
 cpu:                1
 ephemeral-storage:  13285667614
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             397152Ki
 pods:               110
System Info:
 Machine ID:                 455146bc2c2f478a859bf39ac2641d79
 System UUID:                68F543D7-EDBF-4AF6-8354-A99D96D994EF
 Boot ID:                    5775abf1-97dc-411f-a5a0-67f51cc8daf3
 Kernel Version:             4.4.206-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
 OS Image:                   CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
 Operating System:           linux
 Architecture:               amd64
 Container Runtime Version:  docker://18.6.3
 Kubelet Version:            v1.13.0
 Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.13.0
Non-terminated Pods:         (2 in total)
  Namespace                  Name                    CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                  ----                    ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                    ng2-569d45c6b5-ppkwg    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         26h
  kube-system                weave-net-pbb86         20m (2%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         26h
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests  Limits
  --------           --------  ------
  cpu                20m (2%)  0 (0%)
  memory             0 (0%)    0 (0%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)    0 (0%)
Events:              <none>
```

Comment: Please, can you add more information to your question? Output of commands showing this behavior, what cloud provider are you using, if you are following a how to (share it). The more information you give, easier is to figure out what is happening.

Comment: Updated the question with more info

Comment: What's the output for `$ kubectl describe nodes`?

Comment: Updated the output above

Comment: I can see that you have different IPs not only in your pods, but also in your nodes. As you can see in the `kubectl describe node` output InternalIP for worker1 is 192.168.5.12 and for worker2 is 10.0.2.15.

This is not expected, so make sure you have attached both of your VirtualBox VMs with the same adapter type. Both should be in the same network and seems like they are not and that would explain this behavior.

Comment: Thanks mWatney for pointing it out. I really missed that. The first node i manually added on the cluster and the second node was added by TLS boot strap. Something would have gone wrong in that process iguess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you have different IPs not only in your pods, but also in your nodes.

As you can see in the `kubectl describe node` output `InternalIP` for `worker1` is `192.168.5.12` and for `worker2` is `10.0.2.15`.

This is not expected behavior, so it's important to make sure you have attached both of your VirtualBox VMs to the same adapter type.

Both should be in the same network and in the comments you confirmed that this was the case and that explains this behavior.

Here is an example of that configuration:

[image: VirtualBox Adapter Settings]

As you mentioned on comments, the first node was added manually and the second was added during the TLS bootstraping and it got added even with "wrong" IP Address.

To solve this issue the best thing you can do is to bootstrap you cluster from scratch again using the same Adapter Settings on Virtual Box for all nodes.

Comment: All the nodes including master has 2 interfaces. One host only adapter for internal traffic and one Nat adapter for internet. First worker node picked the host only adapter and the second node picked the Nat adapter for some reason

Comment: I followed all instructions from the tutorial "Kubernetes the hard way using VirtualBox" and for me everything is working as expected. I would suggest you to follow the tutorial again and bootstrap a new cluster to see if the same problem will happen.

Comment: I added the private ip of the worker node as --node-ip parameter in kubelet service file and readding the node to the cluster worked fine. also had to clear the weave database on 2 of the worker node and recreate the weave pods to get the networking working as expected. All good now. Thanks much for your help :)